# Well written for-loop doesn't work in browser console

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, browser, console

So i was trying to make a password generator, and I want to get random letters and numbers from different arrays and assign to a variable which will now serve as the generated password, and now to increase the length of the characters in password i make to for loop add two random uppercase and lowercase letters and a number every time for 15 times and I'm pretty sure i wrote it well but when i tested in chrome's console it returned undefined immediately without the loop even running. Then i tried even the most basic loop in the console and the same thing happened, sometimes my browser just freezes like it's an infinite loop but it's not.

### Here is a copy of a basic loop

```
 for (var z=0; z>=5 ; z++) {console.log(z);}
```

The code above is the loop i use that my browser malfunctions, but i noticed one thing which is that the loop works when i increment the variable by 3 times its value i.e x*=3.

```
  for (var x=3; x<10000 ; x*=3) {console.log(x);}
```

I really need your opinion on this I've tried the first in multiple browsers on my pc and I still get the same results. I don't know if the problem is from my browser.

#### here is my google drive link for the images

[Click here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1PahuLVE0Woup1BWDD-_rsX9EmniA5yGa)

Comment: It will help if you edit the question and include the code in question.

Comment: I've uploaded like to screenshots in my Google drive. Thanks

Comment: You should copy and past the code into the question. Indent four spaces before each line and it will even format it nicely.

Comment: [Please don't share images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2745495) or external links to Google Drive, etc. because those links can disappear over time. Instead, add the code directly into the post and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to display them as text. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One of your for-loop looks like `for(var z = 0; z >= 5; z++) {}` Why you're expecting iterarion with that condition and that initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry condition is not satisfied in your loop due to >= check

Your code:
 for (var z=0; z>=5 ; z++) {console.log(z);}

It should be (assuming you want to iterate 5 times):
 for (var z=0; z<5 ; z++) {console.log(z);}

Hope this helps.